# Android app : Resource not found when building with an older API

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am getting the following error when I build my app targeting API 23

```
AAPT: error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
```

and a list of error like :

```
/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3217: error: resource android:attr/textFontWeight not found.
```

The app builds on API level 29 but I need it to work on API 23 precisely so **changing the API version is not an option**.
is there any way I could use an old layout maybe ? the app does not need to be pretty at all, it just needs to work.

edit :
I added the following line :
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'`
to build.grade (:app) in hope that the library would provide the resources but it did not work

but I might have added it wrong

Answer (score 1):

`android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored` was added in API 24, so when building for devices with 23 you are getting this error. solution will be to implement `MaterialComponents` [library](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started), which will allow you to use newer styles/widgets on older devices. look for `View` which is causing your problem and replace it with above library or set compat style

Comment: thanks, I tried it and it changed something. I edited the post

Comment: you've imported it right, but it won't bring you exactly same theme name - this would be naming conflict on newer devices. all built-in attributes are starting with `android:` prefix, those from libraries (or local custom) won't have this prefix. you may try to remove `android:` keeping rest (starting `style/TextAppearance...`), but I doubt it work, you have to read some doc and look for equivalent with changed naming, e.g. `.Material.` part may change to `.MaterialCompat.` (and use it without `android:` prefix also)

Comment: that is very useful information thank you, i'll try to check for non android: resources